# UIAnimations in response to MIDI events in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, audiotoolbox, coremidi

I am trying to program a MIDI sequence using Apple's AudioToolbox framework that triggers animations in the UI. I've been successful in creating the sequence thanks to Gene De Lisa's blog which I won't replicate here in its entirety due to the length of the code. The basic process was setting up an AUGraph, a sampler unit (AudioUnit()), a musicPlayer and a music sequence:

```
var processingGraph:AUGraph
var samplerUnit:AudioUnit
var musicPlayer:MusicPlayer
var musicSequence:MusicSequence
```

then I made a function to populate the music sequence:

```
func createMusicSequence(quality: Int, root: UInt8, interval: UInt8) -> MusicSequence {
    // create the sequence
    var musicSequence = MusicSequence()

    var status = NewMusicSequence(&musicSequence)
    if status != OSStatus(noErr) {
        print("\(__LINE__) bad status \(status) creating sequence")
        CheckError(status)
    }

    MusicSequenceSetAUGraph(musicSequence, self.processingGraph)

    status = MusicSequenceNewTrack(musicSequence, &trackOne)
    CheckError(status)

    status = MusicSequenceNewTrack(musicSequence, &trackTwo)
    CheckError(status)

    status = MusicTrackSetDestNode(trackOne, samplerNode)
    CheckError(status)

    status = MusicTrackSetDestNode(trackTwo, samplerNodeTwo)
    CheckError(status)

    var beat = MusicTimeStamp(0)
    var i = 1
    while i <= 4 {
        var mess = MIDINoteMessage(channel: 0,
            note: 60,
            velocity: 64,
            releaseVelocity: 0,
            duration: 1.0 )
        status = MusicTrackNewMIDINoteEvent(trackOne, beat, &mess)
        if status != OSStatus(noErr) {
            CheckError(status)
        }
        beat++
        i++
    }

    switch quality{
        case 0: flexiChord(root, transFunc: interval, chordQuality: maj7)
        case 1: flexiChord(root, transFunc: interval, chordQuality: min7)
        case 2: flexiChord(root, transFunc: interval, chordQuality: dom7sharpNineFive)
        default: print("error creating sequence")
    }

    loopTrack(trackOne)
    loopTrack(trackTwo)

    status = MusicSequenceNewTrack(musicSequence, &trackThree)

    MusicSequenceGetTempoTrack(musicSequence, &trackThree)

    self.musicPlayer = createPlayer(musicSequence)

    return musicSequence
}
```

SO...I cannot understand how to detect note events and animate the UI based upon them in real time--I understand that setting the user callback or midi endpoint have to do with this, but I am using swift and there seems to be little documentation that I'm able to understand out there on this subject. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a virtual destination using `MIDIDestinationCreateWithBlock`
In your readblock you will get a packetlist. Iterate through them and do your animation. If you want sound, your readblock will have to forward the packet to your sampler with `MusicDeviceMIDIEvent`